# Крашается программа при OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

Попробовал написать простую программу:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

в итоге при запуске этого кода программа тупо зависает, а через время крашается.Так же с папками, пробовал множество программ, пробовал скидывать другу программу (у него тоже крашнулась), в чем проблема?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.20.php

Comment: заметил то что если создать новый проект и написать точно такой же код, все прекрасно работает

Comment: Надо писать хотя-бы что за ошибка возникает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, нужно методу Main дать атрибут STAThread

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() ...
```